# How to add custom arabic font for pdf in pug file in node js project

Tags: node.js, pug, wkhtmltopdf, font-family, arabic-support

I am using wkhtmltopdf libarary to convert pug file to PDF and in pug file I have text in arabic and english but I want specific font for arabic text to show in PDF file

I tried it but it is giving the error.

```
html  
  head
    title #{salesDetail.invoiceNumber}
    style 
      .arabic-text
        font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif
```

---

`app/views/sale/sales.pug:7:22 5| style 6| .arabic-text > 7| font-family: 'Tajawal' , sans-serif ----------------------------^ 8| body 9| if salesDetail.OldSale && salesDetail.deletedAt 10| div(style={'position': 'absolute' , 'z-index': 0, 'background': 'white' , 'display': 'block' , 'width': '100%' , 'text-align': 'center'}) unexpected text "'Taja"`

---

This approach is giving above error